# Bison Parser: trouble in print token

Tags: c, bison, yacc

I already do some change , i try to change $$ to $2 but i still  with error becuase i dont recognize T_NUM and  T_STR , and it showing that error:
$$ linha' Does not have a declared type

bison -d -o gram.c pro.y:

```
pro.y:45.32-33: erro: $$ linha Does not have a declared type
 linha: ESCREVER lista ';' { if($$.u.type==T_STR){
                                ^^
pro.y:46.48-49: erro: $$ de linha Does not have a declared type
                                printf("[%s]\n",$$.u.str);
                                                ^^
pro.y:49.43-44: erro: $$  linha Does not have a declared type
                                    assert($$.u.type==T_NUM);
                                           ^^
pro.y:50.50-51: erro: $$ linha Does not have a declared type
                                    printf("%d\n",$$.u.num);
                                                  ^^
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'gram.c' failed
make: *** [gram.c] Error 1
```

**bison/yacc code(update)**

```
%{

  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "pro.h"
  int yylex(void);
  int yyerror(const char *s);
%}

%code requires
{
enum TokenType{ T_STR ,T_NUM };

}

%union{

  struct token{

    enum TokenType type;
    union{ char *str;
          int num;
         };
               }u;
      }


%token TERMINAR ESCREVER
%token SUBTRACAO 
%token MULTIPLICACAO 
%token DIVISAO 
%token SOMA
%token<u.num> NUM 
%token<u.str> TEXTO 
%type<u> elemento
%type<u.num> expr 
%type<u> lista
%start s

%%

s:linha s
 |TERMINAR ';' {return 0;}
 ;

linha: ESCREVER lista ';' { if($$.u.type==T_STR){
                               printf("[%s]\n",$$.u.str);
                                                } 
                            else{
                                   assert($$.u.type==T_NUM);
                                   printf("%d\n",$$.u.num);


                                        }}
     | VARS
     ;

lista: elemento { $$=$1; }
     | lista ',' elemento 
     ;

elemento:TEXTO { $<u.str>$=$1;}
        |expr  { $<u.num>$=$1;}
        ;





VARS :
     | NUM 
     | TEXTO
     | expr
     | TEXTO '=' VARS ';' /* para delcaracoes */
     ;



expr     : NUM  SOMA expr                {$$=$1+$3;}
         | NUM  SUBTRACAO expr           {$$=$1-$3;}
         | NUM  MULTIPLICACAO expr       {$$=$1*$3;}
         | NUM  DIVISAO expr             {$$=$1/$3;}
     | NUM  '+' expr                 {$$=$1+$3;}
         | NUM  '=' expr                 {$$=$1=$3;}
         | NUM  '-' expr                  {$$=$1-$3;}
         | NUM  '*' expr                 {$$=$1*$3;}
         | NUM  '/' expr                  {$$=$1/$3;}
         | NUM                           {$$=$1;   }
         ;             


%%
```

Comment: I guess you can do `lista: elemento { $$=$1; puts($1.str);}`.

Comment: @DYZ you think will work in `linha: ESCREVER lista ';'`

Comment: Printing a non-terminal is usually harder than a terminal. You can try, of course. You will need a loop over `lista`.

Comment: It's not immediately clear why you have a struct inside your union.  It undoes the benefit of using a union in the first place.  However, it could be that it is a side-effect of creating an MCVE ([MCVE]), in which case, you're excused.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  check the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to tell whether you've got a `u.str` or `u.num` value to work with — this is normally done by adding a flag to indicate which you have.  So, you might have a `u.type` element in the structure, and you'd set it to `T_STR` or `T_NUM` (values from an enumeration, perhaps), and then you can do:

```
if ($$.u.type == T_STR)
    printf("str: [%s]\n", $$.u.str);
else
{
    assert($$.u.type == T_NUM);  // Make sure it gets changed with more types
    printf("num: %d\n", $$.u.num);
}
```

You might well factor that into a function, in fact; it is often useful to be able to dump structures on demand.  You'd need to think about whether the structure should have a tag so you can reference the type more easily.

```
%{
enum TokenType { T_STR, T_NUM };
%}

%union {

   struct token
   {
       enum TokenType type;
       union
       {
           char *str;
           int   num;
       };
   } u;
}
```

This uses the anonymous union types added in C11.  You can now pass a `struct token *` into a function that prints the data appropriately.

Comment: You don't need to use a `%union` declaration if all grammar symbols have the same `struct` type, which is quite common when using discriminated unions. Unfortunately, bison doesn't have any mechanism to automatically set the discriminator, unless you change to the C++ interface and use variant types. Anyway, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Structured-Value-Type for very brief documentation.

Comment: @rici: I agree about a single structure in `%union` being ... undesirable; I'm assuming that this is a stripped down MCVE and that there would be other structures in the union in the full code.  (Maybe I'm being too charitable, but we can pretend.). Sometime, I'll look up the reference — it may be more immediately useful to the OP.  At least I think I've given decent pointers in the right general direction; that may help the OP get the rest of the way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i try but the it is showing this error : ** error: field ‘type’ has incomplete type enum TokenType type; **
                    ^

Comment: You're likely to need to update the question, *adding* new material (not modifying the existing material) so that the information can be properly formatted.  Please make sure it is as close to an MCVE as possible.  That said, did you include the `%{ … %}` section I showed?  If so, I'll have to play a bit; you need to be able to use user-defined types in unions.

Comment: The fallback is to make `type` an `int` and perhaps use defines instead of the `enum`.

Comment: yes i included `%{ %}` , you are saying i need use `enum TokenType { T_STR, T_NUM }; ` inside union?

Comment: Tl;dr: `%code requires { enum TokenType { T_STR, T_NUM }; }` so that the `enum` declaration ends up in the generated header file. The lexer (from which that error comes) needs the declaration in order to compile the semantic type `YYSTYPE`. Longer description in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Prologue-Alternatives)

Comment: @rici %code requires work but now i have a question how did compiler will know `T_STR` is for string and `T_NUM` for integer , how i can declarate this?

Comment: @Duboskydumont: Succinctly, the compiler doesn't know (that `T_STR` is for string type and `T_NUM` is for integer type); you need to write the code so that it is correct.  This is usual in language parsers written in C plus Bison plus Flex, at least in my experience.  Basically, C doesn't have a 'discriminated union' type, unlike Pascal variant records, for example.  So, since the compiler doesn't know about this, the programmer must.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler iam trying do something like that `elemento:
      TEXTO {
       $$.type = T_STR;
       $$.u.strval = $1;
     }

    | expr {
       $$.type = T_NUM;
       $$.u.intval = $1;
      }
    ;` and than use ur if code

Comment: If you have a union as I suggested, you can only store either an integer _or_ a string but not both. So, when using `T_STR`, do not set `$$.u.intval`.

Comment: but i cant figure out how to set string in T_STR , i guess is impossible , i have experiencie only in C#